# weird footer space apperas from nowhere... IE7 problems

Tags: css, footer

I've problem with ie7, for some reason, strange extra space appears near the footer.

Could you help me diagnose this issue?

I wasted two days trying to do something...

See it in action here: http://artvard.com/category.html

Footer is kind of a sticky version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this bit of code at the end is causing your issue. I think IE7 thinks there might be some HTML to be rendered there:

```
<script>
    (function(d, t) {
        var g = d.createElement(t),
    s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.async = true;
        g.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
     })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

A nice trick with JavaScript is that you can wrap HTML comments around it and it still functions as JavaScript without affecting your HTML layout. I personally use it to get around xHTML validation, but it may help you here too:

```
<!--
    <script>
        (function(d, t) {
            var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.async = true;
            g.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
         })(document, 'script');
    </script> 
-->
```

This may not be your answer, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but footer problem also is present on this page: http://artvard.com/main.html where I don't have any js in footer :s

Comment: btw this <!--
 makes javascript not function at all! because code is within body tag

Comment: That's no good! Nice to know though about the comments in the body. My next thought would be the height on the .wrapfooter class. Try commenting out the height and see what happens. Sorry to lead you astray.